# Как убрать автоматическую подстановку домена в Denwer

Tags: denwer, localhost

предположим создаю сайт под названием "Index" на локалхосте.
и это самое имя сайта (Index) подставляется в начало всех ссылок. как этого избежать?

Допустим я создаю в пределах сайта ссылку(даже пустую например) <a href="">Ссылка</a>
Вместо же пустой ссылки создается ссылка в которой адресом значится Index

Comment: ну так ссылки то относительные... так и должно быть. Если хотите абсолютные - то указывайте в href полный путь: http://blabla ...

Comment: изначально пытался писать абсолютную ссылку в виде www.blabla.com, но ничего не вышло. Поэтому и затупил.

Вообщем, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Абсолютные и относительные ссылки](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki)